# Do I need to use Content Type with Search Results Web Part?

Tags: 2013, content-type, search-results

My goal is to display all the items in a specific list using the Search Results Web Part. I created a Result Type and set ListID to equal my list.

I've added a Search Results Web Part, but there doesn't seem to be an option to show just my Result Types. I do see an option named "Items matching a content type (System)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Content Search webpart to page and edit the web part properties
2. Click on Change Query - This will open the query builder modal dialog
3. In order to display the list items from a specific list - Enter the list URL in the Restrict app section
4. Click Switch to Advanced Mode
5. Remove the text that check for file extensions (Query text)
6. Click OK and Save the page

Comment: Not working for me. To clarify, this is a custom list. What's the view name?

Comment: @matt updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else reading this I had to take off the AllItems.aspx from the list URL.